# Elements Missing From Windows Forms App (.NET Core) when run on non-development PCs

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

I've recently developed my first windows forms app (.NET Core), and it runs great on my native machine, but I've run into some problems when deploying to others. It started out with an unhandled exception occurring related to the font size on the pages being 'NaN', so I added some exception handling logic that now allows the program to launch on other PCs, but any forms element that utilizes the Font is not showing up. I have some dynamic font scaling in the application, but disabling this didn't fix any issues, all of the text boxes and buttons that contain a font field are blank.

Since this only occurs on other PCs and not the development computer I've been working on, I realize that it could be a dependency issue, but I'm not quite sure how.

Also, just to cover my bases, I'm using the publish tool in visual studio and simply copying the .exe and .dlls that are compiled in Visual studio and then placing them on a flash drive to transfer to 2 other test PCs to ensure the application is portable.

Here's the handler that I use for re-sizing screen elements and font sizing. I added the "Nan" logic to get through the exception, but it seems there's a deeper problem, but I currently have no idea what it is!

`

```
private void ResizeControl(Rectangle r, Control c, float h)
        {
            float xRatio = Width / (float)(originalFormSize.Width);
            float yRatio = Height / (float)(originalFormSize.Height);

            int newX = (int)(r.Location.X * xRatio);
            int newY = (int)(r.Location.Y * yRatio);

            int newWidth = (int)(r.Width * xRatio);
            int newHeight = (int)(r.Height * yRatio);

            float newFontSize = (h * ((xRatio + yRatio) / 2));
            Math.Floor(newFontSize);
            
            if (float.IsNaN(newFontSize))
            {
                newFontSize = h;
            }
            if (newFontSize == 0)
            {
                newFontSize = 24.0f;
            }


            c.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
            c.Size = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
            Font newFont = new("Segoe UI", newFontSize, FontStyle.Regular);
            Font = newFont;
            selectionBox.Font = Font;
        }
```

`

Comment: You should put some logging code in there so that you can see exactly what the code is doing on the other machine. You can write the results of each operation to a file and then you can see whether they are what you expect.

Comment: Check whether `originalFormSize.Width` or `originalFormSize.Height` are `0` on the affected machines - this would cause your font size calculation to resolve to `NaN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some logging and checking on the form sizing, it turns out that many of the buttons and other tools in the application were getting re-sized before the form was loading, and were getting set to 0. I noticed this occurring on the development PC as well. I added a flag to not do any re-sizing until after the form was loaded, and this fixed the issue on my local machine as well as the test machines.